# sql search function issue, LIKE and MATCH

Tags: sql, match, sql-like

I had to fix a problem in someone else's code where a search function was returning too many results, I noticed it was using MATCH< where LIKE would be more appropriate.

I am not too good on SQL and I have changed all the MATCH's to LIKE's..

This has obviously brought on an error, I assume its to do with the AGAINST which im not sure but could be only be working with MATCH..

Here is the statement in the asp code.

```
    strSQL = ""
        strSQL  = "SELECT 'case-studies' AS pagetype, cs.title AS entrytitle, cs.casestudyid AS id, csi.casestudyimageid AS imageid, csi.imagetitle,  LIKE (cs.title, cs.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance, LIKE (csi.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS imagerelevance "
        strSQL = strSQL & "FROM casestudies AS cs, casestudiesimages AS csi "
        strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE cs.casestudyid = csi.casestudyid AND cs.modestatus = '1' AND ((LIKE(cs.title, cs.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR (LIKE(csi.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR (cs.title like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (cs.content like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (csi.imagetitle like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "
        strSQL = strSQL & "UNION ALL "
        strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT 'news' AS pagetype, news.title AS entrytitle, news.newsid AS id, newsimages.newsimageid AS imageid, newsimages.imagetitle, LIKE (news.title, news.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance, LIKE (newsimages.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS imagerelevance "
        strSQL = strSQL & "FROM news, newsimages "
        strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE news.newsid = newsimages.newsid AND news.modestatus = '1' AND ((LIKE(news.title, news.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR (LIKE(newsimages.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR (news.title like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (news.content like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (newsimages.imagetitle like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "          
        strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "
        strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC, imagerelevance DESC "
```

Can anyone help decipher this code.. It needs to search on like for like, as opposed searching "he" and getting "help" etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MyISAM and there are full-text indexes on the the  columns you wish to search, you can avoid full-table scans by using "MATCH....AGAINST" rather than LIKE, which is much more efficient. I have replaced the "LIKEs" in those places where MATCH is appropriate - followed by AGAINST in your code. The general rule with your SQL is, if the expression to test does not have wildcard characters (ONLY % in this case), use MATCH.

```
strSQL  = "SELECT 'case-studies' AS pagetype, cs.title AS entrytitle, 
          cs.casestudyid AS id, csi.casestudyimageid AS imageid, csi.imagetitle,
          MATCH (cs.title, cs.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance, 
          MATCH (csi.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS imagerelevance "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM casestudies AS cs, casestudiesimages AS csi "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE cs.casestudyid = csi.casestudyid AND cs.modestatus = '1' AND
    ((MATCH (cs.title, cs.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR
    (MATCH (csi.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR 
    (cs.title LIKE '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (cs.content LIKE '%" & 
     searchfor & "%') OR (csi.imagetitle LIKE '%" & searchfor & "%')) "
strSQL = strSQL & "UNION ALL "
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT 'news' AS pagetype, news.title AS entrytitle, 
        news.newsid AS id, newsimages.newsimageid AS imageid, newsimages.imagetitle, 
        MATCH (news.title, news.content) 
        AGINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance, 
        MATCH (newsimages.imagetitle) 
        AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS imagerelevance "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM news, newsimages "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE news.newsid = newsimages.newsid AND news.modestatus = '1'
         AND ((MATCH (news.title, news.content) 
                 AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR
        (MATCH (newsimages.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' 
        IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR (news.title LIKE '%" & searchfor & "%') 
        OR (news.content LIKE '%" & searchfor & "%') 
        OR (newsimages.imagetitle LIKE '%" & searchfor & "%')) "          
    strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC, imagerelevance DESC "
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying LIKE but you are not comparing your LIKE to anything, a valid LIKE statement is

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE CUSTOMERNAME LIKE '%' + @Param+ '%'
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, All I did was change the MATCH to a LIKE, so I assumed it'll all be wrong... The problem lies with me having a lack of knowledgein SQL...  Can you have more than one LIKE in a row?

Comment: Hi Paul, yes you can have more than one LIKE in your statement. But you will always have to define it like above. so then you add AND and then columnname like ..., same way all over again :)